# Where does the Host store the documents used in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is there a folder in the Host where the files used in the Guest are stored? Specifically, I refer to documents, text files et similia. 
I found several posts about file sharing between the two OSs, but they do not answer this question. Actually, on the Host I found only the VM configuration files.

I mean, it is a VM, ok, but they have to physically stay somewhere on the Host HD! What if I want to access them without starting the WM?

My usual config:
W10 - Host; 
Lubuntu - Guest.

Comment: In a virtual hard disk file.

Comment: Do you mean that those files are never physically written on the Host HD?

Comment: No; they're written to a virtual hard disk file.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to get the concept. If those files are not physically fixed somewhere, how do they not disappear when the VM (and the host) is shut down?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of virtual disk you use VDI, VMDK, VHD, or HDD.

VDI is an issue. The only way i've found so far is to use a USB drive to copy things off and on, or create a network share.

If you're using VMDK, Vmware has a tool I believe is called VMware disk mount as a part of their VDDK, and you should be able to use it to mount VMDK disks as hard drives. https://developercenter.vmware.com/web/dp/sdk/55/vddk

Windows VHD is the easiest one to work with. You can use "Computer Management" on your windows PC to mount the VHD as an external drive using this tutorial. http://notebooks.com/2011/02/25/how-to-browse-and-copy-files-from-a-vhd-system-image-backup/

I'm really not sure about HDD.

Comment: Windows VHD appears to be an interesting solution, at least for my needs. Do you mean that I can mount a Linux Guest with VHD e then mount its HD as an external drive in the Windows Host?

Comment: You should be able to do that, yes. I'm not sure if you'll have problems with the linux filesystem types being unreadable by windows, but as long as you take that into consideration and use filesystems both can read you should be fine.